# Trying upload large file from formData

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I trying upload large file (over 200mb) via FormData and xmlHTTPRequest like this

```
var fd = new FormData;
fd.append('files[]', file);

xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", url, true);
xmlHttpRequest.send(fd);
```

in php script i have

```
<?php
var_dump("IN");
var_dump($_FILES);
```

out:

```
IN
array()
```

Request wait 10 second and finish. With smaller files all good, without FormData (simple ajax from) all good. all settings in php.ini have max value. what's wrong?

if it can help, this is my request header:

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Cache-Control no-cache
Content-Length 294561150
Content-Type multipart/form-data
Host test1
Referer http://test1/
User-Agen Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest
```

Response header:

```
Connection close
Content-Encodin gzip
Content-Length 51
Content-Type text/html
Date Sat, 29 Jun 2013 23:03:26 GMT
Server Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By PHP/5.4.17RC1
```

My /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 512M
max_file_uploads = 20
max_input_time = 10000
memory_limit = 2048M
max_execution_time = 10000
post_max_size = 1024M
```

My scripts link: http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/430866/test1-tar-gz.html

PS It's run all times **10 seconds** and then finish.

Comment: You said all settings in PHP.ini have max values but how do we know you set the correct settings? Post your php.ini settings that you changed.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your php.ini file, these are things that will affect upload and you need to change them accordingly

```
file_uploads
upload_max_filesize
max_input_time
memory_limit
max_execution_time 
post_max_size
```

All those settings have to have a reasonably high setting for larger files. Becareful not to make your memory_limit too high which can be dangerous. I'd maybe do `128MB`. `max_execution_time` is forgotten by many and the default is `30` secs. Not long enough for large files. I set mine to `1000` since I handle large videos. It is a common reason why the script doesn't finish and will finish prematurely. You may or may not have to restart your web server.